# What is Electron Excitement in the Bohr model?

Tags: electrons, atomic-physics

Is electron excitement the absorption of a photon thereby causing an electron to move to a higher energy level?

In my textbooks, electron excitement is implicitly implied to mean that an electron goes from a higher energy level to a lower one. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

In general, when a bound system is said to be excited, it is in a state other than the ground state. So when an atom absorbs a photon, it's energy increases and it gets into an excited state. However, it is not possible to say what your textbooks mean by an excited state without further context.